# Jenkins. При создании проекта не выполняется git remote на новой ноде

Tags: git, jenkins

Доброго времени суток.
Застрял при работе с нодами в Jenkins. Прошу помощи.

Суть проблемы:
добавил ноду с windows для jenkins, всё настроено по мануалу и всё корректно работает. На ноде так же присутствует git с интеграцией в explorer.

При создании проекта для сборки, в разделе с git указываю линк на репозиторий, в ответ:

Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://blabla.ru/blabla.git HEAD

Предполагаю, что созданный мною проект в jenkins "трётся" об мастер ноду, которая вообще отключена, да и гита на ней нет.

1. Нужна ли мастер нода и для чего?
   Если планируется выделение для каждого проекта своей ноды.
2. По стандарту есть инстанс. Называется он default и вместо пути указано просто git.

Попробовал отдебажить в консоли добавленной мной slave ноды:

1) println "git ls-remote ...".execute().text

Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

2) println System.getenv("PATH")

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;

3) println "git —help".execute().text

В ответ пусто.

4) Ок.
Добавил path до bin.
Ребутнул машину.
Проверил path:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;

Попробовал ещё раз вывод:
println "git —help".execute().text

Пусто

5) Удалил путь с bin.
Путь до cmd отредактировал до bin.
Проверил path в консоли - всё ок.
Ребутнул.
Попробовал сделать вывод - пусто.

Отсюда вопрос.
Как "побороть" ошибку, при создании нового проекта в Jenkins?

Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://blabla.ru/blabla.git HEAD

В проекте так же указана новая нода с Windows, которую я ранее добавил в Jenkins, на которой и будет происходить сборка. Git для этой ноды я скачивал и устанавливал с офф. сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
помимо того, что на slave ноде должен быть гит, так и на мастер ноде (где расположен jenkins) тоже должен быть git - именно он и выполняет проверку.

Answer (score 1):

Привет, в конфиге ноды нужно указать путь к гиту
Manage Jenkins> Manage Nodes > windowsnodename > configure

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]